# jmeter json path Conditional Extraction at peer level

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I'm using jmeter v2.13 and jp@gc - JSON Path Extractor.

Here is my `JSON` sample:

```json
{
  "views": [{
      "id": 9701,
      "name": " EBS: EAS: IDC (EAS MBT IDC)",
      "canEdit": true,
      "sprintSupportEnabled": true,
      "filter": {
        "id": 55464,
        "name": "Filter for EBS: EAS: IDC & oBill Boar",
        "query": "project = \"EBS: EAS: IDC\"",
        "owner": {},
        "canEdit": false,
        "isOrderedByRank": true,
        "permissionEntries": [{
          "values": [{
            "type": "Shared with the public",
            "name": ""
          }]
        }]
      },
      "boardAdmins": {}
    },
    {}
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to extract `views[x].id` where there exists an entry `views[x].filter.permissionEntries[*].values[*].type` that equals `Shared with the public`?

How would I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JSON Query would look like this (I admit I didn't try it in JMeter)

```
$.views[?(@.filter[?(@.permissionEntries[?(@.values[?(@.type == "Shared with the public")])])])].id
```

Explanation:

We expect under root (`$`) to have `views` and for it to have property `id`. The rest (in `[]`) are conditions to select only `views` items based on predefined condition. Hence ***$.views[conditions].id***

Conditions in this case are coming one within the other, but main parts are:

- We define condition as a filter `?(...)`
- We ask filter to look under current item (`@`) for a specific child item (`.child`), child may have its own conditions (`[...]`). Hence ***@.child[conditions]***. That way we move through `filter`, `permissionEntries`, `values`
- Finally we get to field `values` and filter it for a child `type` field with particular value `Shared with the public`. Hence ***@.type == "Shared with the public"***

As you see it's not very intuitive, and JSON path is a bit limited. If this is a repetitive issue, and your JSON is even more complicated, you ay consider investing into a scriptable pre-processor (similar to the one explained [here](http://wiki.workassis.com/how-to-use-simple-json-with-jmeter/).